# Pull value from <select> with Javascript and loop

Tags: javascript

Using JavaScript (no jquery) for this project i need to pull the value from a select box and compare it to a predefined value.  If they match, show a message box to the user and then change the select dropdown so it shows the value that was compared

```
function displayRow(PreEvent){

if ((PreEvent != 'null') && (PreEvent !== 0)) {

//var myString = "";
//var splitString = myString.split(':'); 
var splitString = PreEvent.split(':');

for(var i, j = 0; i = document.getElementById('thursevent').getElementsByTagName("option")[j]; j++) {
  var sel = document.getElementById('thursevent').value;
  var splitSel = sel.split(':');

  if(splitSel[3] == splitString[3]) {
    document.getElementById("thursevent").selectedIndex = j;
    break;
  }
}}


<select name="thursevent" id="thursevent" onchange="displayRow(this.value);" >
  <option value="0"> -- Please Select Here -- </option>
  <option value="645:5:227:640">T00</option>
  <option value="563:0:84:654">T01AM</option>
  <option value="564:0:116:563">T01PM</option>
  <option value="565:0:176:640">T02AM</option>
  <option value="566:0:1:640">T02PM</option>
  <option value="567:0:24:640">T03</option>
  <option value="568:0:154:640">T04</option>
  <option value="569:0:108:0">T05</option>
  <option value="570:0:651:0">T06</option>
  <option value="571:0:201:0">T07</option>
</select>
```

--> Updated final example found here:
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3CWy2/18/)

Comment: Though the extra parenthesis aren't really required for that statement, could just as easily be `if (PreEvent != 'null' && PreEvent != 0) {`, which is a little more readable imo.

Comment: What is m? `("option")[m]`

Comment: You are trying to compare array `splitSel` with number `splitString[3]`. What you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You're right.  I'm not explaining this very well.  I updated the code to try and help this.  What i want to do is if the values match, change the dropdown so the index of what matched is now selected.

Comment: Match with what? `splitString` is empty...

Comment: in your example - `myString` empty. Your code - on any change(true or wrong) try select right answer.

Comment: Good eye.  MyString should be fixed now.

Comment: after last edit - you try change select to selected options - it's  
unreason

Comment: Your question is changing all the time, you edit and edit... Try what you need before posting please.

Comment: may be you need add `[1]` or `[0]` to `splitSel` in `splitSel == splitString[3]`. example: `splitSel[1] == splitString[3]`

Comment: @Sergio do not be so cruel, he try explain what he want. Just don't know how it made.

Comment: Sergio - you are right.  My thought was to try and fix the initial question so those who come to it can see what i'm trying to get at; even if it is one step closer.  Sorry for the confusion.  Part of that might be the end of the day and my brain is fried from working in JS all day :)

Comment: @trijin & Web Guy, I'm not cruel. But not fun to go into a problem trying to fix it and the variables of the problem keep changing. What happens is that people drop out and loose interest. Better delete the question, fix it and post it back.

Comment: @WebGuy see this http://jsfiddle.net/3CWy2/6/ in comment several explanations

Comment: @trijin thanks for the suggestions.  I don't think i'm pulling the correct value in the for loop.  If someone picks 'T01PM' i want it to tell them they need to pick 'T01AM' first and then change the dropdown to that.  how do i do that? http://jsfiddle.net/3CWy2/8/

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/trijin/3CWy2/12/ and let's go out from this "_chat_"  my g+ trijin@gmail.com. do you have HangsOut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3CWy2/17/)

I believe I understand what you want.  The data is in the format of `courseNumber:something:something:prerequisite`.  When the user selects an item, we need to check if it has a prerequisite, and change the select element to that prerequisite (plus an alert).

```
function displayRow(PreEvent) {
    if (PreEvent == null || parseInt(PreEvent) === 0) return;
```

First, we should clean up our variables.  It makes the code confusing.

```
    var selectElement = document.getElementById('thursevent');
    var optionElements = selectElement.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var prerequisite = PreEvent.split(':')[3];
```

We can save some work if the prerequisite is 0, because we'll never have a course 0.

```
    if (parseInt(prerequisite) === 0) return;
```

I also changed the variable names here, but the biggest change is we're comparing our prerequisite to the course number of each option.  Note that we're checking index 0 instead of 3, as it was in your previous code.  I believe that was an error.

```
    for (var opt, i = 0; opt = optionElements[i]; i++) {
        var courseNumber = opt.value.split(':')[0];
        if (prerequisite == courseNumber) {
            alert("The course you selected has a pre-requested course.  You must add that to your registration first.");
            selectElement.selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i was trying to get this to do.  Thanks to you (and the others) for getting this working.